# Why image of $f$ in $Aut$(Klein Four Group) is equal to identity element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am learning Abstract Algebra taught by Prof. Gross. In his video lecture [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfIkaq-MV2w&list=PLhsb6tmzSpizcCt38jBla0fW_yHgkHxvu&index=4) at 47:40, he states that the image of $f$ in $Aut(G) = {e}$ where $f : G \rightarrow Aut(G)$. And $G$ is Klein Four Group.

Could anyone tell me why? I could not understand... Thanks in advance!

Comment: He is looking at inner automorphisms, $Inn(G)$, conjugation by elements of $G$. $Inn(G) \cong G/Z(G)$. So if $G$ is abelian, then $G=Z(G)$ and $Inn(G)$ is trivial. By the way $Aut(V_4) \cong S_3$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Many thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Klein four-group is abelian, therefore all inner (conjugation) automorphisms are trivial.

Comment: I want to know why trivial, could you elborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: If $G$ is a abelian then for every $g\in G$ conjugation by an aribtrary element $h$ give $hgh^{-1}=hh^{-1}g=g$  so the "conjugation-by-$h$" automorphism is the identity automorphism, but $h$ was arbitrary, so in fact the conjugation-by-$h$ automorphism is the identity automorphism for all $h\in G$